# UILabel autolayout cut bottom pixels

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, pixel

I constructing `UITableCellView` from xib. This xib uses `autolayout` and two `UILabel`s connected to superview and have vertical constraint.

Unfortunately it is cutting pixel(s) at the bottom of `UILabel`:
[image]

What do I missing?

UPD. Xcode is giving me error: `Set vertical compression resistance priority to 749`. If I play with compression resistance priority I get first label cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the priority on the vertical spacing constraint between the two labels to be lower than the vertical spacing constraint between the labels and the top and bottom of the view. Alternatively, in your delegate, override

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

that will return a height that will accommodate the constraints and label heights. By default I believe you get 44 pixels, so you can get a taller cell by overriding these. Also, you can set the cell height in IB if you're using Storyboards or Nibs.

Comment: Increasing cell height doesn't help. I also update question with xcode error

Comment: Interesting, I usually don't bother changing the compression resistance as I like to leave my elements uncompressed and just give them enough room. @EugenMartynov Did you try changing the cell height to custom on your UITableViewCell in IB?

Comment: I forgot to mention that also changing priority for constraint between labels didn't help. But that constraint has constant 1. So maybe this an issue when it is doing height of cell calculation.

Comment: The height is custom already and increasing height doesn't help

Comment: Typically what happens is if the labels didn't have enough space to fulfill all of its constraints it breaks the one with the lowest priority. What you should be seeing is if the labels don't have enough space, they begin colliding with one another. You do have the following constraints, right? Vertical between cell top and first label, vertical between top label and bottom label and a vertical between the bottom label and the bottom of the cell? You shouldn't need to do anything else.

Comment: @EugenMartynov, also, try changing the cell background color to make sure that the labels do in fact have enough room and that you're setting the cell heights correctly.

Comment: I had additional constraint which actually was shrinking

Comment: If you have a multiline label, this answer is not correct.